# How long should I leave old filter in new tank after installing a second, new filter to replace the old one?

Tags: aquarium, water-parameters, filters, equipment, guppies

Hi I started a tank a week ago with 3 guppies in my daughter's room, but the HOB filter was too loud, so I have now changed to Fluval U2. I have both filters in tank now since yesterday, but my question is: can I remove 1st noisy one, as it has only been in the tank for a week so it hasn't fully cycled yet?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! If you use the point "not fully cycled yet" you should not have animals in it until now. Fish and others should move in AFTER the tank is cycled. That you used both filters in parallel was a good idea in general. Sorry, I do not know, how long it will be, until the useful bacteria growth is enough in the new filter... But I know, we have some specialists here, who will answer your question :)